# MySQL - How to JOIN with an unexisting index?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table in my DB called ORDERS and it looks like this:

ID_section (int), ID_price (int), ID_city (int), ID_company (int)

And I want to use the JOIN method to set names to the ID's.

What I would do is:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS 
JOIN sections ON sections.id=orders.ID_section 
JOIN prices ON prices.id=orders.ID_price 
JOIN cities on cities.id=orders.ID_cities 
JOIN companies ON companies.id=orders.ID_company
```

But the point is, that in ORDERS table can be inserted value of 0 and it means - all the sections/prices/cities/companies, but when I run my query, only the values, that their ID exist in the other table show up.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question correctly and having, for example, `ID_section = 0` means that the order belongs to all the section then the following query should do the trick.

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS 
JOIN sections ON sections.id=orders.ID_section OR orders.ID_section = 0 
JOIN prices ON prices.id=orders.ID_price OR orders.ID_price = 0
JOIN cities on cities.id=orders.ID_cities OR orders.ID_cities = 0
JOIN companies ON companies.id=orders.ID_company OR orders.ID_company = 0
```

If, on the other hand, you want to retrieve all orders regardless if they have sections, prices, etc. associated, then it is sufficient to put `LEFT JOIN` where you have `JOIN`. (But this situation does not result from your question! I only added it because people seem to understand that.)

Comment: This is not correct. As stated in the question, there are no rows with ID = 0 in these tables. :P

Comment: @Mchl So? Where do you see me checking for `id = 0`? I only check for `ID_<category>` being 0.

Comment: Yes. I wrote ID instead of writing full names to save some time.

Comment: @Mchl Why do you say that? He specifies that there are: "in ORDERS table can be inserted value of 0".

Comment: Actually I think you might be right after all, but left join query would work just as well...

Comment: Not exactly. It will only get one instance of the order - although this may be what he wanted. The other problem is, if for example, an order has a city ID of say `432`, but there is no city with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` (which is a shorthand for `INNER JOIN`)

Comment: That is not correct. A left join with return the orders with nothing else associated. He wants **everything** associated when there is a 0 ID.

Comment: That's how YOU understand it. I stand by my answer.

Comment: "value of 0 and it means - **all the** sections/prices/cities/companies" I understand from this that he wants to match everything in that category when the ID_<category> is 0.

Comment: "But the point is, that in ORDERS table can be inserted value of 0" - so the 0 is inserted into orders table, and if matching rows were present in joined tables, than inner joni would find them. Anyway, let's wait for OP for clarificaition

Comment: Well, I could go with the LEFT JOIN method, but I was hoping for something even more eficient, because with the NULL value inserted, I'll have to make some lines of conditions in PHP, that I was hoping to avoid. =/

Comment: If NULLs can also exist in these fields, then go with Alin Purcaru's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with `LEFT` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` s and you'll be able to figure out what you need to do.  Basically a LEFT or RIGHT OUTER JOIN will insert NULLS into columns where no data exists but still do the joins.

There are [various resources](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) on the web that explain this.